# Adding custom field to DocumentInfoValidators

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I want to use a custom field in my PDF metadata. When the PDF loads with pdf.js and examine the contents of `getMetadata()` the field is missing, because it isn't included in the list of valid fields `DocumentInfoValidators`.

If I add my field directly in the pdf.js source I can see my field - but is there a **proper way** to add a custom field name, or is it usual to modify and build my own version?

I'm using pdfjs@1.7.312.

I can see the definition in `pdf.worker.js` around line 39125, in the definition of PDFDocument; then it gets used later in `documentInfo()`

```
var DocumentInfoValidators = {
  get entries() {
   return shadow(this, 'entries', {
    Title: isString,
    Author: isString,
    Subject: isString,
    Keywords: isString,
    Creator: isString,
    Producer: isString,
    CreationDate: isString,
    ModDate: isString,
    Trapped: isName
   });
  }
 };
```

Comment: These probably come from the PDF standard, so you may he generating PDFs that won't open in some readers. Is there somewhere else that you can store this metadata?

Comment: The [itext examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-delete-retrieve-information-pdf-using-custom-property), and the [Acrobat user guide](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-properties-metadata.html) both mention that custom properties are allowed - so I think that pdf.js is providing a sanity check with the most common properties.

Data can also be stored in the XMP metadata - but that will force XML rules, and I don't want to go there :)

Comment: What's wrong with modifying and building your own version?

Comment: I prefer to use npm install the official upstream version. But mostly I want to make sure I have not missed any obvious way to add a custom field name, before I commit to building from a modified version...